# Changing code to adjust number of charts on each powerpoint slide VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have hundred of charts in an excel. The following code creates a powerpoint and pastes the charts into the powerpoint based on a pattern. For example, there are 37 charts that repeat across many dimensions, for example, Total_Portfolio has 37 charts, then CRA_Portfolio has 37 charts, the Fixed_Portfolio has 37 charts..... and this patter continues.

The code below pastes 4 charts per slide for the first 5 slides and then 3 charts on the next slide, and then 1 chart per slide for the next 14 slides.

So, the pattern is 4,4,4,4,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 and that repeats until all dimensions are reported.

If I wanted to adjust the code so that each dimension has 41 charts and the pattern across the slides needs to be 4,2,3,3,3,2,4,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 and then repeat, how would I adjust the below code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyChartsToPowerPoint()

'// excel variables/objects
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
Dim chart_obj As ChartObject
Dim i As Long, last_row As Long, tracker As Long

'// powerpoint variables/objects
Dim pp_app As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pp_presentation As Presentation
Dim pp_slide As Slide
Dim pp_shape As Object
Dim pp_slider_tracker As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set source_sheet = wb.Worksheets("portfolio_charts")
Set pp_app = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pp_presentation = pp_app.Presentations.Add

last_row = source_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
pp_slider_tracker = 1

Set pp_slide = pp_presentation.Slides.Add(pp_slider_tracker, ppLayoutBlank)

For i = 1 To last_row

If i Mod 37 = 5 Or i Mod 37 = 9 Or i Mod 37 = 13 Or i Mod 37 = 17 _
Or i Mod 37 = 21 Or (i Mod 37 > 23 And i Mod 37 < 37) Or i Mod 37 = 0 Or (i Mod 37 = 1 And pp_slider_tracker > 1) Then
pp_slider_tracker = pp_slider_tracker + 1
Set pp_slide = pp_presentation.Slides.Add(pp_slider_tracker, ppLayoutBlank)
End If

Set chart_obj = source_sheet.ChartObjects(source_sheet.Cells(i, "A").Value)
chart_obj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

'Set pp_shape = pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
Set pp_shape = pp_slide.Shapes.Paste

Select Case i Mod 37

Case 1, 5, 9, 13, 17
pp_shape.Left = 66
pp_shape.Top = 86

Case 2, 6, 10, 14, 18
pp_shape.Left = 510
pp_shape.Top = 86

Case 3, 7, 11, 15, 19
pp_shape.Left = 66
pp_shape.Top = 296

Case 4, 8, 12, 16, 20
pp_shape.Left = 510
pp_shape.Top = 296

Case 21
pp_shape.Left = 66
pp_shape.Top = 86

Case 22
pp_shape.Left = 510
pp_shape.Top = 86

Case 23
pp_shape.Left = 66
pp_shape.Top = 296

Case 24 To 37, 0
pp_shape.Left = 192
pp_shape.Top = 90
pp_shape.width = 576
pp_shape.height = 360

End Select

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

Next i

End Sub
```

I have a code that works assuming a pattern of 37 charts - need to adjust for 41 charts.
I looked here: ([Creating a powerpoint with multiple charts on each slide from excel using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946786/creating-a-powerpoint-with-multiple-charts-on-each-slide-from-excel-using-vba)) but that doesn't really address the number of charts per slide.

Comment: How did you create the logic for the 4 charts for 5 slides that the code does already?

Comment: I inherited it - I am trying to work through it ad adjust it .... making progress....but now I think I need to adjust the If i Mod 37 = 5 Or i Mod 37 = 9 Or i Mod 37 = 13 Or i Mod 37 = 17 _
Or i Mod 37 = 21 Or (i Mod 37 > 23 And i Mod 37 < 37) Or i Mod 37 = 0 Or (i Mod 37 = 1 And pp_slider_tracker > 1) Then
pp_slider_tracker = pp_slider_tracker + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really struggled to figure it out but the below seems to work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyChartsToPowerPoint()
    
    '// excel variables/objects
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim chart_obj As ChartObject
    Dim i As Long, last_row As Long, tracker As Long
    
    '// powerpoint variables/objects
    Dim pp_app As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pp_presentation As Presentation
    Dim pp_slide As Slide
    Dim pp_shape As Object
    Dim pp_slider_tracker As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set source_sheet = wb.Worksheets("portfolio_charts")
    
    Set pp_app = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set pp_presentation = pp_app.Presentations.Add
    
    last_row = source_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    pp_slider_tracker = 1
    
    Set pp_slide = pp_presentation.Slides.Add(pp_slider_tracker, ppLayoutBlank)
    
    For i = 1 To last_row
        'Stop
        'Debug.Assert i < 36
        
        If (i Mod 41 = 1 And pp_slider_tracker > 1) Or i Mod 41 = 5 Or i Mod 41 = 7 Or i Mod 41 = 10 Or i Mod 41 = 13 Or i Mod 41 = 16 Or i Mod 41 = 18 Or i Mod 41 = 22 Or i Mod 41 = 24 Or _
        (i Mod 41 > 27 Or i Mod 41 = 0) Then
            
            pp_slider_tracker = pp_slider_tracker + 1
            Set pp_slide = pp_presentation.Slides.Add(pp_slider_tracker, ppLayoutBlank)
            
        End If
        
        Set chart_obj = source_sheet.ChartObjects(source_sheet.Cells(i, "A").Value)
        chart_obj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
                     
        'Set pp_shape = pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        Set pp_shape = pp_slide.Shapes.Paste
        
        Select Case i Mod 41
        
            Case 1, 5, 7, 10, 13, 16, 18, 22, 24
                pp_shape.Left = 66
                pp_shape.Top = 86

            Case 2, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, 19, 23, 25
                pp_shape.Left = 510
                pp_shape.Top = 86

            Case 3, 9, 12, 15, 20, 26
                pp_shape.Left = 66
                pp_shape.Top = 306

            Case 4, 21, 27
                pp_shape.Left = 510
                pp_shape.Top = 306
                
        End Select
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Next i

End Sub
```